# "Restore and Save State" by Cordova?

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I am creating an application that communicates with BLE with cordova.
I want to communicate even if the app is stopped,ｃan I use Cordova to "Restore and Save State"?

Comment: I use 「cordova-plugin-ble-central」plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a background task that can still receive BLE data when your app is closed.

[Check out cordova-plugin-background-mode](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode)

On iOS, you need to read ["Communicating with an External Accessory and Communicating with a Bluetooth Accessory"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) to set up your p-list